# Optimizing API Calls in AWS Lambda

Tags: aws-lambda

I'm currently developing a feature to access a list of Cloud Run services on the Google Cloud Platform via an API.
I'm using AWS Lambda to make API calls to retrieve the list of Cloud Run services for each region. Since there are many regions (approximately 39 regions), making sequential API calls for each region takes about 52 seconds. Is there a way to make this process faster?

I've tried using methods like asynchronous processing and thread pools, but it seems that they are not efficient; it still performs sequentially, and the next region is only processed once the API call for the current region is completed. They can't run in parallel.

Comment: Have you into Lambda concurrent execution? Does your Lambda run thru the list of region or does your lambda execute per region (concurrent execution). Can you add your Lambda code/psuedocode?

Comment: Did you try to run your code locally or having a test case to prove that it is Lambda that is causing your problem. Otherwise it might be related to your code. Pasting that might help a lot

Comment: How much RAM does your Lambda function have?